# Export coordinates as text from a shapefile layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, export, coordinates

How can I export X and Y coordinates from a shapefile layer as a text file in QGIS 3.18?
The height of every point is displayed in the attribute table, the x and y coordinates are not. They can only be accessed by using the object information tool and clicking on them in the map.

Answer (score 6):

If you export your features to CSV you can select `AS_XY` in the Geometry field and it will produce an `X` and `Y` column in the output.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem

Comment: then please accept the answer

Answer (score 3):

You can add coordinates in the layer's CRS to the attribute table with the utterly short expressions `$x` and `$y`.